# How to extract data from a TextBox to a GridView (multiple rows to be displayed in the GridView)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview, datatable

I have used the following code to display data from a TextBox to a GridView without saving the data to the database(Two TextBoxes and a Button). When I enter the Name and City in the TextBoxes, and click on the Button, those values will be displayed in the Gridview. It is working as expected without any errors. But I want to tweak the code a bit so that the GridView should be able to add new data from the Textbox by retaining the old data as it is in the Gridview (**multiple rows should be displayed in the Gridview** instead of single rows).

It is a **web-based** ASP.NET application using C# coding (Visual Studio 2010).

**Can you make the necessary changes to the code given below so as to implement the above functionality?**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

protected void btnTextDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name");
            DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("City");
            dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc2);

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = txtName.Text;
            dr[1] = txtCity.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            gvDisplay.DataSource = dt;
            gvDisplay.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to persists your data between postbacks, you have many options here: by `Session`, `ViewState`, `Cache` and some other.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostback)
    {
         dt = Session["data_table"] as DataTable;
    }
}

protected void btnTextDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (dt == null)
     {
          dt = new DataTable();
          DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name");
          DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("City");
          dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
          dt.Columns.Add(dc2);   
     }

     DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
     dr[0] = txtName.Text;
     dr[1] = txtCity.Text;
     dt.Rows.Add(dr);
     gvDisplay.DataSource = dt;
     gvDisplay.DataBind();

     Session["data_table"] = dt;
}
```

Comment: How can I make these changes using ViewState, and Cache? I want to know the differences please.

Comment: `ViewState` is stored in html (in hidden field) on client-side, `Cache` and `Session` is stored in memory, but they have different options, more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320568/viewstate-vs-cookies-vs-cashing-vs-sessions). Changing code is simple, just change `Session["data_table"]` to `ViewState["data_table"]` or `Cache["data_table"]` :)